# Nexus 9 upgrade to Nougat fails - how can I diagnose the problem?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, nexus-9

I'm trying to OTA upgrade a Nexus 9 tablet running 5.0.1 to Nougat. I download the update, verify, and tell it to install. After a little bit, I get the "dead robot" screen that says "Error".

I did a factory reset, downloaded the update again, ran it again, and got the dead robot again.

I've been googling, but I can't find anything offhand that explains what might be happening.

Is there any way I can debug or diagnose the problem?

Comment: Rooted? System modified? It shouldn't error out if not.

Comment: @AndyYan: Not that I know of. It's a work tablet that we've done very little to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you've already done a factory reset then I assume there's no precious data to be backed up on the device - in that case just grab a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), install appropriate drivers and flash manually. The one for the WiFi variant is already out.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I ended up doing: Side-loading 7.0 from my laptop.